# Intuition behind eigenvector centrality and computation procedure

Tags: graph-theory, network

There are various metrics that are used in social network analysis to estimate/find the influence of a node. Among them are various "centralities" - betweenness centrality, closeness centrality and eigenvector centrality (*Learning agent influence in MAS with complex social networks, 2013 by H. Franks, H. Griffith and S.S. Anand)*.

Betweenness centrality measures the number of shortest paths in a network that pass through $v_i \in V$, where $V$ is a set of nodes in $G(E,V)$. Intuitively it allows us to see how much information is likely to flow through $v_i$.

Closeness centrality measures how quickly information can spread from a given agent and its mathematical definition is straightforward.

Eigenvector centrality is calculated using the principle eigenvector given by the adjacency matrix of the graph under consideration. If $EC(v_i)$ is the eigenvector centrality of $v_i$, then:

$EC(v_i) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)} a_{v_i,v_j} \times EC(v_j)$

where $a_{i,j}$ stands for the entry in the adjacency matrix $A$ and $N(v_i)$ denotes the set of neighbours of $v_i$.

The paper given above says:

*An agent is central if it is connected to other agents that are central, and the measure takes into account both direct and indirect connections between agents*

How does this follow from the definition given above?

What is the intuition?

How do we compute $EC(v_i)$ in practice (definition given above looks recursive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An agent is central if it is connected to other agents that are central $\dots$

The eigenvector centrality $EC\left(v_{i}\right)$ of the vertex $v_{i}$ may be described as a measure of the structural importance of $v_{i}$, proportional to the structural importances of their connected neighbourhood; the eigenvector centralities $EC\left(v_{j}\right)$) of each vertex $v_{j}\in N\left(v_{i}\right)$.

In your definition, the required proportionality is obtained by summing over the neighbourhood set $v_{j}\in N\left(v_{i}\right)$ of the principle vertex $v_{i}$. However, in any simplex network, the entries of the adjacency matrix $a_{v_{i}v_{j}}$ are non-zero whenever the vertex $v_{j}$ is incident to $v_{i}$, and thus, each term $a_{v_{i}v_{j}}EC\left(v_{j}\right)$ is non-zero only if $e_{ij}\in E$.

With this in mind, we may extend the neighbourhood summation to that of a summation over all vertices present in the network, as only the connected vertices will contribute to the eigenvector centrality sum of $v_{i}$. Hence

\begin{equation}
EC\left(v_{i}\right) := \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{v_{j}\in N\left(v_{i}\right)} a_{v_{i}v_{j}}EC\left(v_{j}\right) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{v_{j}\in V} a_{v_{i}v_{j}}EC\left(v_{j}\right)
\end{equation}

By adopting the vector notation $EC := \left(EC\left(v_{i}\right)\right)_{v_{i}\in V} \in \mathbb{R}^{|V|}$, the eigenvector centrality definition can now be expressed in terms of the full adjacency matrix A:
\begin{equation}
EC = \frac{1}{\lambda}A.EC 
\end{equation}
Here, each entry $EC\left(v_{i}\right)$ of the $EC$ vector is proportionally equal to the $i$-th of $A$ multiplied by the whole vector $EC$. Lastly, we obtain the eigenvector equation $\lambda EC = A.EC$, which gives the centrality its name.

> $\dots$ and the measure takes into account both direct and indirect connections between agents

Despite not being widely accepted terminology, the eigenvector centrality is frequently classified as a **radial centrality**, which is the class of centrality metrics that measures structural importance in terms of network walks originating/terminating at a particular desired vertex.

Given the expression $\lambda EC = A.EC$, it is possible to recursively imagine that the eigenvector centrality of $v_{i}$ is proportional to the importance of its neighbours $N\left(v_{i}\right)$, whose importance is proportional to their neighbours, whose importance is proportional on their neighbours, etc$\dots$ I would thus argue that eigenvector centralities do in fact take into "account both direct and indirect connections between agents" as your statement suggests.

> How do we compute $EC\left(v_{i}\right)$ in practice (definition given above looks recursive)?

There are a whole host of computational methods for computing eigenvectors, and thus eigenvector centralities. Arguably the most common of which is a recursively implemented algorithm called the **power iteration** method.